# How to set a HTML page to be viewable in an iframe whose width is less than page itself?

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have a webpage in HTML and related CSS and JS, I am also available with an iFrame whose width is lesser than the webpage, Now I want to display this webpage in the iFrame in a way that nothing gets distorted, in short I want to configure the webpage to get fixed in smaller iFrame as well..

Guide me to make this work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is dodgy, for obvious reasons, but you can do this with CSS transform. Load the iframe in the correct size for the content, then scale the iframe down with transform. Say your content is 1000x1000 and your desired iframe is 500x500.

Load the content in a frame that fits:

```
<iframe id="magic" src="whatever" width="1000" height="1000"></iframe>
```

Then scale it to half the size with CSS:

```
#magic {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
  -moz-transform: scale(0.5);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.5);
  -o-transform: scale(0.5);
  transform: scale(0.5);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Modify the page to be embedded so that no fixed width is set and it adapts to the available width. Doing such things from the embedding page would be *much* harder (if possible at all).

The difficulty of doing this greatly depends on the page content and structure. In the simplest case, just remove all `width` attributes from the HTML document and all `width` settings from the CSS code. Keep a copy of the original, though; it can turn out to be much more difficult, and you may need to retain *some* of the width settings.

Answer (score 0):

IFrame is used for load different websites or pages into your website page. If you want to use IFrame you need to set width and height of the iframe according to your page size on other side you can also use panel rather then developing multiple pages but panel could be use in this case if content page is also you are developing.

Please keep in mind IFrame is used only for load different websites content into your website, You can't change the web content which are loaded using IFrame.

Comment: Web page that you are trying to load inside you page that is also developing in your website or trying to load from other website?